# Query regarding class module and appropriate terminology

Tags: vba

I'm not too familiar with class modules and I have a query with a class I found online however before I can ask about an issue I have with that, I need to know how to phrase the question correctly. Using Pseudo-code to keep it simple...

I have a userform and it has a variable declaration of:

`Private m_ClsVariableName as ClsClassName`

In the UserForm_Intialize event I have:

```
Set m_ClsVariableName = New ClsClassName

With m_ClsVariableName
Set .Subroutine1= Me.CmdButton1
Set .Subroutine2= Me.CmdButton2
Set .List = Me.Listbox1
End With
```

In the class I have these declarations:

```
Public WithEvents Subroutine1                As MSForms.CommandButton
Public WithEvents Subroutine2                As MSForms.CommandButton
Public List                                  As MSForms.ListBox
```

What is the correct terminology that describes using set to assign a subroutine or a variable in the class to a control on the userform (in this case 2 command buttons and a listbox)??

Comment: event sinking or binding perhaps.

Comment: you're simply assigning a class property. it happens this latter has been declared as of one of  `MSForms` objects type which event system has been connected to and let you utilize the events of the object

Comment: @user3598756 Thanks for the clarification. As stated the code above was pseudo code. My actual situation is that I have a class which moves the selected row in a listbox up or down via 2 buttons. This is repeated 2 more times on the form via duplicating the code in the userform_initialize event thus creating 3 instances of the class and changing the control names in the Set lines.My question ultimately is, Can I have 1 pair of buttons move the selected item in (either of the 3 listboxes) up or down via 1 instance of the class connecting each listbox to a single instance of the class?

Comment: ...Continued from above. FWIW I have also set each listbox click event to deselect any previously selected items in the other listboxes. I have tried using (actual code this time) `Set .UpDownList = Me.Listbox1 OR Me.Listbox2 OR Me.Listbox3` but it gives a type mismatch error.

Comment: well this is a completely different issue than this question: you may want to post a new question and show all relevant code as well as giving as many details as possible about issues you encountered and your efforts (even if unsuccessful) to handle them till now

Comment: I thought that might be the case, I've done as you advised and create the following new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958579/moving-single-selected-item-in-1-of-3-listboxes-via-a-class