# Moving single selected item in 1 of 3 listboxes via a class

Tags: vba

Apologies for the awful title, its not the easiest thing to describe. I currently have a form with 3 listbox and adjacent to each 2 command buttons which allows the selected item in the listbox to move up or down. It all works fine but I would like to reduce the number of command buttons to a single pair and operate on the listbox with the currently selected item but I do not know if its possible. The code I have is:

Form declarations(3 instances for each pair of up/down buttons):

```
Private m_clsListMoveUpDown1                 As CListbox_UpDown
Private m_clsListMoveUpDown2                 As CListbox_UpDown
Private m_clsListMoveUpDown3                 As CListbox_UpDown
```

and then instantiating the 3 instances of the class (within the form) via:

```
Set m_clsListMoveUpDown1 = New CListbox_UpDown
With m_clsListMoveUpDown1
Set .MoveDownButton = Me.Btn_MoveDown1
Set .MoveUpButton = Me.Btn_MoveUp1
Set .UpDownList = Me.LB_Sheet1
End With

Set m_clsListMoveUpDown2 = New CListbox_UpDown
With m_clsListMoveUpDown2
Set .MoveDownButton = Me.Btn_MoveDown2
Set .MoveUpButton = Me.Btn_MoveUp2
Set .UpDownList = Me.LB_Sheet2
End With

Set m_clsListMoveUpDown3 = New CListbox_UpDown
With m_clsListMoveUpDown3
Set .MoveDownButton = Me.Btn_MoveDown3
Set .MoveUpButton = Me.Btn_MoveUp3
Set .UpDownList = Me.LB_Sheet3
End With
```

Finally, some class declarations:

```
Public WithEvents MoveUpButton               As MSForms.CommandButton
Public WithEvents MoveDownButton             As MSForms.CommandButton
Public UpDownList                            As MSForms.ListBox
```

I haven't included either of the 2No. subroutines (moving the selected item up or down) within the class but can do if it helps. In a nutshell they contain:

```
With Me.UpDownList
'lines of code using arrays to move items up or down
End With
```

I completely understand the reason why a single pair of up/down buttons currently only operates on the listbox specified by e.g. `Set .UpDownList = Me.LB_Sheet1` but I do not know how to associate the other 2 listboxes so that if either one has a selected item, have the buttons operate on that listbox.

I attempted to use the `Set .UpDownList = Me.LB_Sheet1 or Me.LB_Sheet2 or Me.LB_Sheet2` but the gives a type mismatch error and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: `me.ActiveControl` should help

Comment: also add a typename() check to make sure its a combobox.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for the reply. I don't follow your suggestions, can you expand further? Also, did you mean Listbox instead of Combobox as I don't have any comboboxes on this userform.

Comment: Google it, try what me.activecontrol gives you, look at the help for typename.  I wont write it for you, look at your question "how to refer to the listbox" so I'd start by looking at switching me.updownlist for me.activecontrol as a start.

Comment: Oh I'm not looking for a fully coded answer and I have tested me.activecontrol however it causes an error within the class subroutine relating to which button was pressed whereas it never did before using 3 pairs of buttons. It appears the value of updownlist is set to nothing. I have found using debug.print `FrmMain.ActiveControl.Name` the active control is a frame even though the a listbox within the frame has a selected item.

Comment: so set a public listbox object to the activecontrol on the focus event.  You could take that one stage further and event sink the combos.

Comment: The focus event you refer to, what object does it belong to as I cant see a focus event for a listbox in the IDE dropdown? Of course I am likely misunderstanding your suggestion as working with classes is new to me. I've been looking for examples using the phrasing of your suggestion but I cant determine from the search results if anything listed is what you suggest.

Comment: enter I believe or click or whatever you want to give focus to a listbox to which these buttons will control, so `Private Sub ListBox1_Click(): Set myControlledListbox = Me.ActiveControl: End Sub`

Comment: Ok, I think I am almost there. I ended moving the instantiating class code from the form_initialize event into the listboxes click events. I also added a typename check as suggested.

`Set m_clsListMoveUpDown1 = New CListbox_UpDown                                 
With m_clsListMoveUpDown1
    Set .MoveDownButton = Me.Btn_MoveDown1
    Set .MoveUpButton = Me.Btn_MoveUp1
    If TypeOf ActiveControl Is MSForms.Frame Then
        Set .UpDownList = Me.ActiveControl.ActiveControl
    Else
        Set .UpDownList = Me.ActiveControl
    End If
End With`

Continued below...

Comment: you would need an ActiveControl property in your class, then you'd say on the click event classname.activecontrol=me.activecontrol.  i'll post an answer

Comment: It works but oddly. If I click in the 1st or 3rd listbox, push a button, the row moves. If I move the 2nd listbox, push a button I get an Object variable or With block variable not set error on the up or down button subroutine within the class: `With Me.UpDownList: If Len(.RowSource) > 0 Then Exit Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a class like so

```
Private frmParent As MSForms.UserForm
Private lstListBoxUnderControl As MSForms.ListBox

Public WithEvents UP As MSForms.CommandButton
Public WithEvents DOWN As MSForms.CommandButton

Public Property Set PARENT_FORM(frm As MSForms.UserForm)
    Set frmParent = frm
End Property

Public Property Set LISTBOX_CONTROLLING(lb As MSForms.ListBox)
    Set lstListBoxUnderControl = lb
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    '
End Sub

Private Sub DOWN_Click()
    '   Down Code
    lstListBoxUnderControl.BackColor = vbRed
End Sub

Private Sub UP_Click()
    '   Up Code
    lstListBoxUnderControl.BackColor = vbGreen
End Sub
```

Setting it up in the form like so

```
Dim c As New clsUpdateController

Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Set c.LISTBOX_CONTROLLING = Me.ActiveControl
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Set c.LISTBOX_CONTROLLING = Me.ActiveControl
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox3_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Set c.LISTBOX_CONTROLLING = Me.ActiveControl
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox4_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Set c.LISTBOX_CONTROLLING = Me.ActiveControl
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox5_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Set c.LISTBOX_CONTROLLING = Me.ActiveControl
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set c.PARENT_FORM = Me
    Set c.DOWN = Me.cmdDown
    Set c.UP = Me.cmdUP
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem "test"
    Me.ListBox2.AddItem "test"
    Me.ListBox3.AddItem "test"
    Me.ListBox4.AddItem "test"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, sorry for the delay, I've been away for a couple of days. Thanks for provide an example it helped me understand classes a little more. I tested your example but found it gives a Type Mismatch error under certain circumstances but I can't determine why. I created a new project in excel VBA with a class module and userform. I added an additional line to the class: `Me.ListBox5.AddItem "test"`. The error can be replicated by loading the form, select listbox5, press the either button then select listbox 4 or 3 and it errors but if you select listbox 2 or 1 it doesn't. Continued...

Comment: If you switch the MouseDown event for the Change event it works fine which is odd. Anyway, I've now got my project working as I was looking for so thanks for your help with the issue. I've got one final listbox challenge to attempt but I'm gonna research it first but if I'm struggling I'll post a new question. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, but be careful on multi-selects, glad to be of help.  I mentioned a while back to do a typename check on the object in focus just to be safe.